Lightning-input type="time" resets time value on blur
I have the following simple code, no events wired at all, simply dropping this on an LWC template...
<lightning-input 
  data-id="startTimeNew" 
  type="time" 
  variant="label-hidden" 
  required>
</lightning-input>

When I try to set the time in the lwc like so...

When I tab to the next component (or I should say when this input loses focus) it put the value of 12:00 AM back in the input...

I cannot figure out why this has started happening.
The browser is Chrome.
Anyone else experienced this? How to solve?
Thanks.

Does this happen if you create a test LWC only containing this component reference and no JavaScript?

I'm not seeing this behavior when testing it out in the docs: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/example

@BillWoodson I'm getting the exact same thing - this does not happen in SF's lightning-input docs page when testing the component, but does happen just as you said in my implementation. Very confusing! But it also depends on the prior click behavior. If you click into the field, change it, then tab away, the change is undone. However if you TAB into the field, change it then tab away, the change is kept. Did you ever find a solution?

@BrigLarimer no not yet, but I will test your tabbing behavior that sounds interesting.
